# compare current value with previous value in datastage

Tags: datastage

i have input like below

empid   salary
10      1000
20      2000
30      3000
40      4000

the output i require in a sequential fie is like below. that is prevsal should have the salary of the previous row

empid   salary   prevsal
10      1000     null
20      2000     1000
30      3000     2000
40      4000     3000

i tried using a transformer by giving stage variable as prevsal=inputlink.salary and then defining a output column inputlink.salary=prevsal. i know that doesnt work logically and yes it didnt work. can anyone find me a solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right way - transformer and stage variables is the way to go.
Remember that within the transformer the data is processed top down. This means the first (top most) stage variable is processed first, then the second and so on and finally the data is put on the output links.

Having you input column: inputlink.salary 
Assuming two stagevariables: svPrevSalary (top most)
and a second one svCurrentSalary

Try following assingments in the stage variable section:

```
1. svCurrentSalary  (=) svPrevSalary
2. inputlink.salary (=) svCurrentSalary
```

Use

> svPrevSalary

as derivation of the output link / field.

Please note that the (=) are just the idea you have to specify only svCurrentSalary for the first stage variable.

Comment: you are right. i tried this on my own and got the expected result. Need to mention that APT_COMPUTE_NODE has to be set to 1 for this to work correctly. As the enviroment i tried had default value of compute node as 2 and it generated a different result as multiple compute nodes means rows will be split across the nodes. thank you

Comment: You are not right - this will work as well with multiple nodes - and multiple nodes should be default. You have to partition in the right way and sort the data before the transformer.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem when I started to do.i was not getting the expected result.
For this question, we have to note down 2 things. 
1. for which jobs I m doing.like for the server, sequential or parallel.I am working in the parallel environment.
2. pls remember the order of execution of link i.e i/o order.

code- curr_salary -> Prev_Sal,
       link.salary -> curr_Salary

link to prev_salary output link to prev_salary

**Note**
If you working in the Parallel environment then you have to make a sequential mode in execution section in every stage.
Go to Stage-> advanced -> Excution mode-> sequential.

I think it should work. I did this practically.[Transformer_Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceX2k.png)
thanks